# user.commit () is not working when I am tryinmg to create read only user for Airflow 1.10.10

Tags: python, airflow

I am using MySQL database and upgrading Airflow 1.10.5 to 1.10.10 for which I also want to add feature of read only access for one user. Tried to create new user using https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html but when I ssh to docker container using sudo docker container exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash and perform

```
# navigate to the airflow installation directory
$ cd ~/airflow
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb 10 2015, 03:28:08)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import airflow
>>> from airflow import models, settings
>>> from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
>>> user = PasswordUser(models.User())
>>> user.username = 'new_user_name'
>>> user.email = 'new_user_email@example.com'
>>> user.password = 'set_the_password'
>>> session = settings.Session()
>>> session.add(user)

everything runs fine but afetr this wjhen I run 
>>> session.commit()
```

throwing an error:
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users
[SQL: INSERT INTO users (username, email, superuser, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('read_only_user', 'read_only_user@gmail.com', 0, '$2b$12$xYttXJYzwkIeVA7EkdQgQe8KN7V84dVUw/jqQ.8B/bulOdMcWuwRa')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8) (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/7s2a)

Can anyone let me know why is this so?? and what could be done on this?

Answer (score 0):

This error typically happens when models aren't available in the Database to perform the transaction. This can be anything from `initdb` not being run at all; `initdb` not having fully completed (leading to some race condition; the context executing the Python doesn't have access to the service on which `initdb` has been run.

Do follow these through, and let us know if the problem remains.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Issue was with DB my executor=Sequential executor and maintaining db is SQL Lite. There is script in entrypoint.sh for commands of sqllite like initdb . So I created new user under it using $CMD create_user -u admin -l airflow -f airflow -e pooja@nice.com -r Admin -p admin before start webserver and sfter $CMD initdb. using this problem isresolved.